# Why is int[] considered an object instead an array of objects

Tags: java, json

I was making a JSON builder lib in java, my lib has a little bug. I noticed because when I changed the type of the "suit" variable to `int[]` instead of `Integer[]` my lib stopped working properly. Well my idea was to let the second `addProperty(..., Object[] value)` method overload the first method `addProperty(..., Object value).`

```
package mypack;

public class JSON {
    private static String $s = "\"";
    private String name, json = "{";

    public JSON() {
        this.name = null;
    }

    public JSON(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = "var " + name + " = ";
    }

    public String getJson() {
        return json;
    }

    public void addAttribute(String attribute, Object value){
        json += $s + attribute + $s + ": ";

        if(value instanceof JSON){
            json += ((JSON) value).json + ", ";
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            json += $s + value + $s + ", ";
        } else {
            json += value + ", ";
        }
    }

    //THIS SHOULD BE USED BY int[].... I think :(
    public void addAttribute(String attribute, Object[] value){
        json += $s + attribute + $s + ": [";

        for (int i = 0; i <value.length; i++) {
            if(value[i] instanceof JSON){
                json += ((JSON) value[i]).json + ", ";
            } else if (value[i] instanceof String) {
                json += $s + value[i] + $s + ", ";
            } else {
                json += value[i] + ", ";
            }
        }
        json = json.substring(0, json.length() - 1) + "], ";
    }

    public void build(){
        json = json.substring(0, json.length() - 2) + "}";
        json = (name == null) ? json : (name + json);
    }
}
```

To test it I used this:

```
package mypack;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] suit = {1,2,3};
        JSON json = new JSON();
        json.addAttribute("x", "suit");
        json.addAttribute("y", suit );
        json.build();
        System.out.print(json.getJson());
    }
}
```

PD: Please don't answer suggesting to use a pre-made lib. I am studying and in the universities we use to be Sisyphus pupils, redo things over and over again until the end of time.

Comment: Well, sure, it's an array of objects, but it's also an array, which makes it an object in its own right.

Comment: It is not an array of objects. It's an array of `int`s.

Comment: It is not recommended to use `$` in variable names.  For one thing, it makes people think you're accidentally posting Perl code with a Java tag.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question is exactly, Java is not Javascript and Java objects are not Javascript objects. In Java an `int` is a primitive type, and arrays are objects (they have a length field).

Comment: The question is asking why `int[]` is not a subtype of `Object[]`. The code example could definitely be shortened to make it more clear, but it's a perfectly valid question that we can answer. Please reopen.

Comment: In Java, an `int` isn't an object.  It's that simple.

Comment: Sisyphus syndrome is when *"a person forces (him)self to undertake [an] impossible task, refusing to accept the fact that he will be unsuccessful."*.  1) This is not an impossible task.  2) You are not being forced to do it.  Feel free to drop out :-) 3)  You (as an individual) only need to do it once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a simplified rewording of your question:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        foo(new int[]{1,2,3});
    }

    static void foo(Object o) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }

    static void foo(Object[] o) {
        System.out.println("array");
    }
}
```

> Why does this print "object" instead of "array"?

Answer: `int[]` isn't a subtype of `Object[]` because `int` isn't a subtype of `Object`.

Java's type hierarchy does not have a supremum, so unfortunately it's impossible to write a method with a parameter that can be any type (or any array). This is why, if you look at APIs like [java.util.Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), you'll see a lot of methods that are repeated for `byte[]`, `char[]`, `double[]`, `float[]`, `int[]`, `long[]`, `short[]`, and `Object[]`.

Comment: I love the way how you explain it. :)

Comment: @ajb - Isn't that just "Gramma"?

Comment: @HotLicks No, my gramma wouldn't have known about that term either.  :) :) Actually, I have a good background in set theory but still don't recall ever seeing the word--the books I learned from all used "least upper bound".